# Can we create a venv for python and use that venv in other folders in VSCode, Windows 10?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-10, modulenotfounderror

- Operating System: windows10
- editor: VSCode (installed extensions: python, Code Runner.)
- Python installed on my machine: 3.9.0

1- My project is in this folder "D:\darsy\Python\Learning\Code with Mosh - The Complete Python Programming Course for Beginners 2019-4\11- Popular Python Packages\code\7- Web Scraping\PyCrawler2"

2- I have app.py in this folder

3- I opened this folder in VSCode.

4- I opened VSCode terminal and run this command:
D:\darsy\Python\Learning\Code with Mosh - The Complete Python Programming Course for Beginners 2019-4\11- Popular Python Packages\code\7- Web Scraping\PyCrawler2> pipenv install requests

5- so I have a venv in this directory: "C:\Users\Acer.virtualenvs\PyCrawler2-RWWuk_HY"

6- I changed my python interpreter in VSCode to this venv.

7- I write this code in my app.py file

```
import requests
```

8- in VSCode terminal, I run this command:

D:\darsy\Python\Learning\Code with Mosh - The Complete Python Programming Course for Beginners 2019-4\11- Popular Python Packages\code\7- Web Scraping\PyCrawler2> python app.py

9- I got this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests' .

why? I have installed requests package in my venv.

I think it's not specific to this package. any package I install and want to use I get this issue.

Thanks for your helps in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please select the virtual environment you created in the lower left corner of VS Code, and then use the shortcut key Ctrl+Shift+` to open a new VS Code terminal, it will automatically enter the selected environment:

Then click the run button in the upper right corner of Vs code:

[image]

In addition, it is recommended that you use the green run button provided by the "Python" extension to run the code in 'Terminal'.

Comment: I set the new environment, but the problem not solved. These sentences of your comment helped me and solved the problem "Then click the run button in the upper right corner of Vs code:" and "In addition, it is recommended that you use the green run button provided by the "Python" extension to run the code in 'Terminal'." Thank you. also I found out I should first activate venv with "pipenv shell".

Comment: @Zighol  -Yes, the reason is that the terminal where you run the code does not enter the created virtual environment, so VS Code cannot find the module.

Answer (score 1):

In order for your app to use the packages installed in the virtual environment, the env needs to be activated.

Activate it by running:

```
source myenv/bin/activate # linux
python -m venv c:\path\to\myenv # windows
```

where `myenv` is replaced by the name of your virtual environment.

You can tell that an env is activated because it will show up at the beginning of each line in your terminal like this: `(myenv) user@DESKTOP-001:`

After that, when you run `python run.py` your app will automatically use the packages installed in the env.

You can also check out [the virtual environment docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#module-venv)

Comment: I run "python -m venv C:\Users\Acer\.virtualenvs\PyCrawler2-RWWuk_HY" in VSCode 
 integrated termina and I got this error: " Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\Acer\\.virtualenvs\\PyCrawler2-RWWuk_HY\\Scripts\\python.exe' "

Answer (score 0):

before running the program I should activate the venv, for this run:

```
pipenv shell
```